# Matplotlib stacked area plot is very jagged and not connected

Tags: python, matplotlib, simulation, stacked-chart, stacked-area-chart

I've been experimenting with simulating different biological and ecological processes. Right now I'm doing evolution and adaptation and am experimenting with green beard altruism. I am attempting to do a stacked plot so I can see the relationship between the sizes of two groups of organisms. Here is the code:

```
def plot_results(self):
    plt.stackplot(self.generation_marks, self.num_alts, self.num_alts, labels=['Number of Altruists', 'Number of Cowards'])
    plt.xlabel('Reproductive Generation', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Number of Cowards and Altruists', fontsize=14)
    plt.xticks(scipy.arange(0, self.generation, 100))
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

However, it looks very jagged and unconnected:

[image]

Sample Data:

X (each generation):
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29]

Y1 (number of altruists):
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 9, 3, 6, 4, 10, 4, 8, 3, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

y2 (number of cowards)
[3, 6, 6, 12, 12, 23, 18, 35, 18, 32, 17, 33, 17, 31, 16, 31, 16, 33, 17, 38, 18, 39, 20, 42, 20, 40, 20, 41, 20, 41, 20, 40, 20, 42, 20, 37, 20, 40, 20, 36, 20, 38, 20, 39, 20, 37, 20, 39, 20, 37, 20, 39, 20, 36, 20, 39, 20, 39, 20, 41]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I provided some sample data that corresponds with the graph. I am also confused why the blue doesn't go to zero if the data it corresponds to went to zero for the second half of the simulation

Comment: Note that your plot command is plotting `num_alts` twice instead of `num_alts, num_cowards`.

Comment: Looking at your data, the jaggedness seems normal since the values continue going up and down (`12, 23, 18, 35, 18, 32, 17, ...`). What's your desired output?

Comment: Before trying the `stackplot`, you should really test out a single plot, e.g. just X vs Y1 and check whether that is what you expect. Then the same for X vs Y2. The repeating X-values look a bit strange. Once the data is in the suitable format, you can start testing the `stackplot` (which doesn't seem to be a problem apart from using `num_alts` twice).